# How to solve the `meteor Js` websoket interrupted while the page was loading?

Tags: meteor

I am new to `meteorJs` how to solve the below warning while web page is loading.while  i am running meteor js app  below  warning came into browser console.How to solve this warning please suggest me.

```
Warning:
The connection to wss://ddp--5346-hcaresample.meteor.com/sockjs/611/6mo4f_7i/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading. @ http://hcaresample.meteor.com/b41c48c8636277a85e3a081bf7c1c8e4c50816d2.js:4
```

Comment: What browser/version are you using? I do not get the warning when I go the page.

Comment: I am also seeing this error with a recent release, the error is showing in Firefox 33, Meteor version 0.9.4

Comment: I'm also seeing this - on my live prod/dev/test domains - eg https://www.crowdcourier.cc/ will show  I am also running an nginx reverse proxy in front that maps the port 3000 to 443 adding ssl. When I visit http://localhost:3000/ the error disappears. It actually seems a bit intermitant, and in testing just now I started to wonder if service work was involved, as it was only appear just after clicking refresh, but not for initial page load etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting your policy?
Like this:

```
import { BrowserPolicy } from 'meteor/browser-policy-common';

    let origin = "ddp--5346-hcaresample.meteor.com";
    BrowserPolicy.content.allowConnectOrigin("wss://" + origin);

    origin = "https://" + origin;
    console.log(origin);
    BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll(origin);
    BrowserPolicy.content.allowEval(origin);
    BrowserPolicy.content.allowInlineScripts(origin);
    BrowserPolicy.content.allowScriptOrigin(origin);
    BrowserPolicy.content.allowImageOrigin(origin);
    BrowserPolicy.content.allowConnectOrigin(origin);
```